# How to strip a pandas datetime of date, hours and seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

How do I remove Date, Hours and Seconds from a pandas datetime, so that I'm left with only the minutes? I have a table of dates in the format:

```
Date
2015-04-18 23:33:58
2015-04-19 14:32:08
2015-04-20 18:42:44
2015-04-20 21:41:19
```

and I want:

```
Date
33
32
42
41
```

The code I'm trying to use is:

```
fiveMin['Date'] = fiveMin['Date'] - pd.Timedelta(fiveMin['Date'], unit='s')
```

to remove the seconds, however I'm getting the error:

```
Value must be Timedelta, string, integer, float, timedelta or convertible
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the dtype is already `datetime` you can use [`dt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.minute.html#pandas.Series.dt.minute) accessor to return just the minute attribute:

```
In [43]:
df['Date'].dt.minute

Out[43]:
0    33
1    32
2    42
3    41
Name: Date, dtype: int64
```

If needed convert using [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas.to_datetime):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])`
```

If the dates are strings and are well formed you could just split on `:` and extract the second to last split:

```
In [46]:
df['Date'].str.split(':').str[-2]

Out[46]:
0    33
1    32
2    42
3    41
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

This returns a string series however, if you want ints then you can cast to int using `astype(int)`:

```
In [47]:
(df['Date'].str.split(':').str[-2]).astype(int)

Out[47]:
0    33
1    32
2    42
3    41
Name: Date, dtype: int32
```